# Moving a sprite diagonal?

Tags: java, android, game-mechanics

I wonder how I should increase and decrease the value of `xPos` and `yPos` to be able to move a sprite object diagonal and in different angles?

```
canvas.drawBitmap(image, xPos - (image.getWidth() / 2), yPos - (image.getHeight() / 2), null);
```

Comment: -1, Really trivial to work out, lack of effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casper gave a good answer, but you can also use *sin* and *cos* to move your sprite at a certain angle:

```
sprite.x += sin(angle) * amount;
sprite.y += cos(angle) * amount;
```

Of course, depending on what Sine and Cosine functions you're using, you may have to enter the angle in *radians/degrees*. Seeing as you're using Java, [java.lang.Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) comes with all the functions you'll need.

For more about *sin* and *cos*, [look at this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry/basic-trigonometry/basic_trig_ratios/v/basic-trigonometry).

Comment: I personally would discourage using sin and cos and just explain a bit linear algebra using vectors. But whatevs works for the person.

Comment: @Sidar Vectors are useful in some cases, yes, but if you want to work with angles you're gonna have to use some trigonometry at some point.

Answer (score 1):

How about just working it out?

Assuming a coordinate system where 0, 0 is top-left.
Defining our object's coordinates as being 0, 0 (x, y).

```
object.x += 50;
object.y += 50;
```

would move the object 50 pixels diagonally towards the bottom right corner.

Comment: What's even the point of answering his question? I know it's easy to do (and a trivial way of getting +15 rep), but IMHO he should have to put in some work himself. Still, good answer to a bad question.